# Databinding a TabItem to a parent Window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, itemssource

I'm trying to clean up the way I use DataContexts with my UserControls, and currently am running into a problem where I need to databind a UserControl inside of a TabItem to the parent Window's DataContext.

Here is a sketch of what my Window looks like:

[image]

As you can see, this Window owns a TabControl that contains TabItems that are dynamically added via the "Tabs" ItemSource.  Databinding at this point is working because "Tabs" gets populated with Tab 1.

Tab 1 contains a UserControl that needs access to multiple string properties in the DiagnosticsViewModel, but when I run my application, the Output window indicates that all bindings have failed.  For example:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
>   AncestorType='System.Windows.Window', AncestorLevel='1''.
>   BindingExpression:Path=Property1; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'Tab1UserControl' (Name=''); target property is 'UCName' (type
>   'String')

The XAML for the UserControl in Tab 1 looks something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <uc:Tab1UserControl UCName="{Binding Property1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
</Grid>
```

where UCName is a String DependencyProperty.

If I am telling WPF that I want to look up the tree and bind to the DataContext for the nearest Window, and my Window's DataContext is set to DiagnosticsViewModel, why isn't it using it for my UserControl's DataContext?  I have not set `DataContext = this` in my UserControl, as I have done improperly many times in the past, with the expectation that my UserControl will be able to inherit the DataContext from its parent.

I would like to see if Snoop can shed light on my problem, but this GUI is being displayed from a MFC application, and Snoop doesn't seem to be able to attach to my WPF dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the source of a binding using RelativeSource, ElementName or the like, the binding will be directly to the element you specify - not its data context. Which means that in your code the user control will try to bind to a property called Property1 on the Diagnostics class itself.

Try using

```
<Grid>
    <uc:Tab1UserControl UCName="{Binding Path=DataContext.Property1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
</Grid>
```

in the code for your user control and see if that fixes the problem.

(As an aside, the idea of the user control itself knowing that the window it belongs to will have a datacontext with a given property seems like a code smell to me, especially since the point of user controls is that they're reusable - it'd feel better to have a dependency property on the user control and then bind that to the appropriate property when you use it. This may just be due to me lacking context, though.)

Comment: thanks, I could have sworn I tried that already and it didn't work, but I just added it again and it seems to have made one of the properties work.  I will double-check and then mark yours as the answer if it checks out!

Comment: regarding your last comment, UCName in my UserControl *is* a DependencyProperty, and I am doing it this way so that the consumer of the UserControl can set one of its initial property values.  Does that sound like a more acceptable approach?

Comment: Sorry, I read the binding as being in the definition of the user control itself instead of where it was being used by the tab for some reason. The way you're doing it is a perfectly acceptable approach, and I don't know how I misread that!

Comment: cool, thanks for the clarification and of course, your helpful answer.